# Combining results of 2 survey sources

Tags: survey, count-data, population

In my study, I have data from 2 survey sources (from 2 groups of people). They are very different from each others. A few major differences:

- First group did not get paid to answer the survey while the 2nd group did (money is the main reason the 2nd group did survey).
- The number of people who are shown the survey in the 1st group and the number of people who answer the survey in the 1st group is a lot bigger than the 2nd group
- Each group of people are shown the survey in their respective platform (e.g.: the 1st group is shown the survey on Youtube, the 2nd group is shown the survey on Facebook). Clearly the platform which the users use affect whether they are shown the survey.
- The response rate is a lot higher in 2nd group compare to the 1st group (for money reasons)
  ...

I am just wondering whether there are any papers and resources which describe how to combine the results of 2 different survey sources. Thanks

Comment: Will you be assuming that every response from each survey is a unique individual, whether combined or not?

Comment: You go to some lengths to describe differences between the two groups, so it seems wrong to combine then as if they are each sample from the same population. //  If the questions are the same, it might be interesting to do tests to see whether you can establish specific ways in which the results of the two surveys differ.